# JS: Create report on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, pdf

I need to create a report (text file), which has tables and images.

First i used `pdfkit` : 
- it can add a picture, but the creation of table is not possible. Only to draw many lines - it's not very good.

Another option to create a file using `excel-export` : 
- creating a table is perfect, but there is no way to add image.

Anyone knows module, which combines addition of images and creation of simple table?

Comment: why people give minus - What's wrong with my question

Comment: Not was me who gave you minus, but what is obvious is your question is to wide. You have to narrow it a little bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found answer in other lib - `html-pdf`

Very easy to use. You can read about it in more detail [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf)